# Null Returned When Reading JSON File with AJAX

Tags: javascript, ajax, json

I have some JS code that reads a JSON file in and stores the object:

```
var queryString = (function () {
  var queryString = null;
  $.ajax({
      'async': false,
      'global': false,
      'url': 'scripts/largeJson.json',
      'dataType': "json",
      'success': function (data) {
          queryString = data;
      }
  });
  return queryString;
})(); 
console.log("LargeJson:" + JSON.stringify(queryString));
```

This works in general, with a small JSON file, I have no problems, and the JSON object is correctly stored in the queryString variable and correctly printed at the last line.

However, when I am using a larger json file (~700 lines), the queryString variable will be null at the last line of this snippet.  I should be running this code synchronously due to the `async` param. What could be going on here? Does this indicate that my larger file is in some way corrupt? I have run it through a few validators with no problems.

Comment: is this a race condition? Perhaps with a longer JSON string, it returns before the value is set.

Comment: My understanding is that the 'async': false param would force this code to run synchronously, and thus no race conditions like that would be possible.

Comment: Also, I would not call this a duplicate question, as my question is concerned with why one valid json file would work whereas another might fail.  The duplicate question marked concerns asynchronous code and a misunderstanding of callbacks.

Comment: The answer to the question also states that syncronous AJAX is really bad. And to use it syncronously you should use `return jqXHR.responseText;`

Comment: keiv's comment is valid. There's no reason to use a callback if you're doing it sync.